# Eclipse: How to add Google Play Services to Extras in Android SDK Manager?

Tags: android, eclipse, google-play-services, extras

Please see the picture. 
I know that Google Play Services must be here, but it is not here.
How can I add GooglePlayServices to Eclipse?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all. I solved my problem.

I have another one Android SDK for Android Studio located in my case here 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio1\sdk'

Then I copied folder 'c:\Program Files (x86)\Android\android-studio1\sdk\extras\google\google_play_services\' to 'c:\Android\android-sdk\extras\google\' (this SDK is for Eclipse).

After that GooglePlayServices was appear in Extras package of Android SDK Manager.

Answer (score 1):

unchecked  `INSTTALLED`  in android sdk manager

[image]

Answer (score 1):

[Update your SDK](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) and make sure you're using the up to date version of ADT (Android Developer Tools).